# "Losing" the address to my root in a binary tree after successful insertion

Tags: c, pointers, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

**Objective**

I am attempting to implement a binary tree sort in C from the pseudocode located at the wiki page on **Tree Sort**(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_sort).

**Problem/Observation**

Symptom: Segfault upon entering the InOrder function.

Within the TreeSort function(responsible for passing all of the collection items to the Insert function), after all of the insertions, but before I call the InOrder function which is responsible for printing the sorted tree node keys, I am losing my access to my root pointer. Because the root address is initialized within the same function that InOrder is called(TreeSort), I don't think I'm losing it due to a scope issue.

**What I have done to fix the problem**

Working function by function and watching the parameters through GDB compiler's debugger, I was able to see that all of the values in my source array/collection were properly initialized and each child node pointer was being properly allocated as needed. I have attempted to include print statements in my debugging to observe the state of certain parameters but none of them are printing and the program is going to directly to a SEGFAULT after I input the array length.

Note: I am aware that an error of 'segmentation fault' means I attempted to access restricted memory. The address has been lost. As such, the address passed to InOrder is 0x0, according to the GDB debugger.

**Where the problem is located(to the best of my knowledge)**

I have traced the address issue specifically to the line after initialization of all tree nodes when I call InOrder. I have included the full code at the behest of someone looking to assist me. It is listed below.

**Additional comments**

I am aware that I will need to destroy/free each of the initialized child Nodes that I have created. Because I am working on a basic implementation, I will add an appropriate function to handle the disposal of those nodes in the time it takes to receive a response, or shortly thereafter.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <time.h>
 
typedef struct binTree binTree;
 
struct binTree {
    binTree* leftNode;
    binTree* rightNode;
    int key;
};
 
void Insert(binTree* Node, int item);
void InOrder(binTree* Node);
void TreeSort(int* numberArr, int length);
binTree* createNode();
int* fillArray(int length);
 
int main() {
 
    int* numberArray;
    int lengthArray;
 
    printf("Length of array of items: ");
    scanf("%d", &lengthArray);
 
    numberArray = fillArray(lengthArray);
 
    TreeSort(numberArray, lengthArray);
 
    free(numberArray);
 
    return 0;
}
 
int* fillArray(int length) {
 
    time_t t;
    int* array = malloc(length * sizeof(int));
 
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));
 
    for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        *(array + i) =  (rand() % 50) + 1; // random num 1-50
    }
 
    for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        printf("%d ", *(array + i));
    }
 
    return array;
}
 
void TreeSort(int* array, int length) {
    binTree* root = calloc(1, sizeof(binTree)); // root
 
    for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        Insert(root, *(array + i));
    }
 
    InOrder(root);
}
 
void Insert(binTree* Node, int item) {
    if(Node->key == 0) {
        Node->key = item;
    }
    else {
        if(item < Node->key) {
            Node->leftNode = createNode();
            Insert(Node->leftNode, item);
        }
        else {
            Node->rightNode = createNode();
            Insert(Node->rightNode, item);
        }
    }
}
 
void InOrder(binTree* Node) {
    if(Node->key == 0) {
        printf("Leaf found!\n");
    }
    else {
        InOrder(Node->leftNode);
        printf("Node: %d", Node->key);
        InOrder(Node->rightNode);
    }
}
 
binTree* createNode() {
    binTree* Node;
 
    Node = calloc(1, sizeof(binTree));
 
    return Node;
}
```

Thank you in advance for your insight and advice.

Comment: Problem looks to be in your `InOrder` function. Please paste that code into the question (external code links should be avoided here as they can become stale). It does not check whether `Node` is NULL or not before dereferencing it.

Comment: @kaylum I have replaced the snippet with the full code. Thank you for the instruction.

Comment: *The address has been lost.*. You are assuming it is the first `InOrder` call that triggers the seg fault. But the function is recursive. So have you actually determined that is the case by dumping the stack trace? It is more likely to be one of the recursive calls since the function does not check for NULL `Node` as mentioned in my previous comment. Add this code to the top of the function `if (!Node) return;`

Comment: @kaylum Thank you! I have replaced the first conditional in the InOrder with the NULL check and it is now printing the root and the ends of each of root's children. On the off chance, is there an obvious reason why it's not printing each of the nodes above the end node as it returns to the parent?

Comment: I was able to clean it up and print all the nodes. Thanks again for the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Your `InOrder` function assumes that leaf nodes can be identified by checking if the `key` is zero.

However, your Insert function doesn't ensure that. Consequently you end up dereferencing a NULL pointer.

As a simple example consider a case with just a single element with value 42. When you call `Insert` your tree will become:

```
                          root -> --------------------
                                  | key = 42         |
                                  | rightNode = NULL |
                                  | leftNode = NULL  |
                                  --------------------
```

Then call `InOrder` with this tree. The first call will be fine but the second call (recursive call) will pass a NULL pointer and then you do:

```
if(Node->key == 0)
```

which will crash because `Node` is NULL.

Also notice that your `Insert` function is wrong. It keeps adding new nodes directly under the `root`. That's wrong. You need to "go down" in the tree until you have a node where `rightNode` or `leftNode` is NULL. Then you can create a new node.

In other words - only do stuff like `Node->leftNode = createNode();` when `Node->leftNode` is NULL.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the clarity of your visualization and explanation. I am now firmly grounded in the understanding of checking directly for the Node pointer NULL state, rather than the data values of the members.

Comment: blessssss. It was printing just 3 nodes and this is why. Thank youuuuuu.

Comment: @Jcode94 Make a drawing of the tree on paper - that will help you a lot. Use some simple input values instead of many random value. For instance try: `Insert(42); Insert(41); Insert(40);` Now "execute the code in your head while making the tree drawing"

Comment: Your last edit made it amply clear. After you did that I did make a drawing and it clicked. Went in and manually added another nested if-else to each of the Insert else conditions to check for NULL and got all of my Nodes print sequentially. I am so happy rn. Thank you for the edits. <3